# "Unbiased" Intro to Old Testament

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, hebrew-bible, teaching

I teach Intro to Old Testament at a community college. I am looking for something that may be a unicorn.But, I am going to ask anyway. Does anyone know of an Intro to Old Testament that does not assume the validity of the critical approach, but is also not explicitly written for confessional evangelicals?

Comment: No such thing. We all bring a bias to the text: hence the study of hermeneutics! Unfortunately, these types of questions are off topic here, but it is something we could certainly discuss [on meta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: But in the meantime, check out [this free online course](https://oyc.yale.edu/religious-studies/rlst-145) and her textbook recommendations, [including the book she wrote specifically for the course.](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Bible-Open-Yale-Courses/dp/0300181795/)

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of the myth of neutrality, that is why I put “Unbaised” in quotes. Thanks, I will repost on meta.

Comment: I am look for a text that takes a confessional (conservative evangelical) approach, but is not explicitly written for a Christian College/University.

Comment: If you’re looking for a specific religious perspective, you may get some help on meta but also ask on [Christianity.SE], assuming a Christian perspective. But it sounds like this is not a religious course so a resource without such a perspective would likely be best.

Comment: As noted, this is off topic as "[bibliography requests](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/are-bibliography-requests-on-topic)," while related to hermeneutics, are too subjective and more broadly on SE networks, a "[product recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad/185486#185486)" request.

Comment: The best way to deal with the inherent biases is probably to set multiple texts from different approaches, and get your students to critically evaluate and analyse them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Van Dempsey,

Why don’t you consider authoring it yourself? 
In doing so, you might consider the following:

•   Employing Bakhtin's theory of *dialogism*

•   Ordering portions of the *Tanakh* (which is *not* identical to the Old Testament/Covenant in my opinion) in sequence alongside a timeline of the major events experienced by the chosen people.

•   Starting shallow and then deepening the information as you discover more connections in the text.

As you pointed out, your goal is not to be hyper-critical, hyper-orthodox, or anything else but simply “Here’s what it says and here’s what was going on at the time.”

Actually, this sounds like a juicy project to me! It might already have been done.

Incidentally, I appreciated your pun on unicorns. There are *nine* unicorns in the Septuagint translation, which were carried along in several subsequent translations.  Do you already know where they came from and why? It has to do with translating the Hebrew word *re’em*. That's a great story with which to start your Chapter 1.

Yes, this is totally off topic, but really fun!

Dieter